# Calling REST APIs from PHP with curl

Tags: api, php, curl

I've successfully received an access token thru the API, but no matter what I do I keep getting this "INVALID_SESSION_ID". Does this mean the access key is invalid? I've tried lots of suggestions from StackExchange here but nothing has worked. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
    $data = [[
        'FirstName' => 'Johnny',
        'LastName' => 'Appleseed',
    ]];

    $token = 'XXX';
    $instance = 'https://XXX.salesforce.com';

    // Initialize
    $request = curl_init( $instance . '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Contact' );

    // Set Options
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ]);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: application/json' ]);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );

    // Make Request
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($request));

    // Close Request
    curl_close($request);
```

Comment: How are you getting access tokne?

Comment: You may start here: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pK8BQAU
Have you tried the token been the combination of pass+token?

Comment: I'm making a "grant_type=authorization_code" request with the auth code and API Keys. I've only tried the token authentication - are you saying try "CURLOPT_USERPWD" and use the token for that?

Comment: You might find these Salesforce PHP clients/libs useful versus writing raw requests: [uuf6429](https://github.com/uuf6429/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/tree/Major-refactor#forcecom-toolkit-for-php) [goetas](https://github.com/goetas-webservices/salesforce-enterprise-client)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed to include all headers as an array. Apparently you can't have multiple CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER options, they need to be included in a single array!

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: OAuth '.$token,
        'Content-Type: application/json', 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for a simple curl example to read data.
This page was first listed in Google, found an easy and clear code example here: https://choy.medium.com/accessing-salesforce-data-via-rest-username-password-oauth-flow-to-a-connected-app-using-php-curl-f1aa37fb463f

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/174000)

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Link-only answers are discouraged, and may be deleted. *(See: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers))* Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/374477/edit) you answer to add more information. *(From [How do I write a good answer?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "...please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link....")*

Answer (score -1):

Try using array for header and token,

`curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( $token, "Content-Type: application/json", "cache-control: no-cache" ));`

I added cache-control, as most server-sides cache their responses. in first try we may get fresh one, but subsequent ones will be cached. Old practice was to add a random variable to the end of the link to keep the results fresh. If you need fresh results use cache control, or pretty ones are ok.
Of course whether this method will work is dependent on the server or website we’re sending the HTTP request to.
We can also add no-store to make sure request shouldn’t be cached at all

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/373884/edit) your answer to explain how this is different from and/or better than the self-solutioned answer.